# Meteor user accounts register only 1 user by email

Tags: meteor

I'm using **Meteor User accounts** with multiples services (google, facebook, ...)

I don't understand why when I'm registering with google and facebook with the same email address, mongodb creating 2 different accounts.

I'm using the default Meteor User accounts settings.

(I have no code to show you)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Meteor doesn't merge user accounts from different services based on email address. If the user's login credentials aren't present in the database yet, a new user gets created. Automatically merging Facebook, Google, and email/password credentials is a potential security hole.

However, I believe it's possible to merge them manually. Login credentials are stored in `db.users.services` document, and it should be possible to have more than one login method per user. I wouldn't recommend that though.

Comment: Why wouldn't you recommend it?

Comment: For example, if you register with email and password, and an attacker, say, hacks your Facebook account, then he can use that to register to the site, and take over your account because of the merge.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to ensure the same email isn't used twice, you can do this:

```
Accounts.onCreateUser(function(options, user) {
  var service, serviceName;
  if (!user.profile) {
    user.profile = options.profile || {};
  }

  if(user.services) {
    // Get first service
    serviceName = _.keys(user.services)[0];
    user.meta.service = serviceName;

    if (!user.emails || !user.emails.length) {
      if(serviceName === "facebook" || serviceName === "google") {
        service = user.services[serviceName];
        user.emails = user.emails || [];

        user.emails[0] = {
          address: service.email,
          verified: service.verified_email
        };

      }
    }
  }

  return user;
});
```

This will add the email field from the provider in the users "email" field, and it will prevent users from registering twice with two different accounts.